# puppet agent -t does not output anything to stdout

Tags: puppet

I updated the server and the agent to version 4.8 → 5.5 and now I have no output to the console, only to the logs.

But `puppet apply` works perfectly.

Maybe someone knows how can I get output again?

```
$cat /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
[main]
  codedir          = /etc/puppetlabs/code
  confdir          = /etc/puppet
  logdir           = /var/log/puppet
  vardir           = /var/lib/puppet
  ssldir           = $vardir/ssl
  rundir           = /var/run/puppet
  factpath         = $vardir/lib/facter
  disable_warnings = deprecations

[agent]
  environment      = production
  server           = ***
  certname         = ***
  report           = true
  show_diff        = true
  logdest          = /var/log/puppet.log

[master]
  certname         = puppet.gegi.co
  dns_alt_names    = puppet-ec2,gegi-puppet-ec2
  environment      = production
  codedir          = /etc/puppetlabs/code
  cadir            = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puppet agent` isn't displaying messages to the console because the `logdest` configuration setting in `puppet.conf` has told it to send logs to a file.

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/configuration.html#logdest

If you want messages to always go to the console, remove the `logdest` variable from `puppet.conf`. If you just want to display messages temporarily, you can use the `--logdest` option to `puppet agent`.

```
puppet agent -t --logdest=console
```

Comment: Thank you! What I was looking for